# How to view active arrow (next / previous) by slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

I have a very simple slideshow on my website, I use a great plugin for slideshow - [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). My problem is with the arrows (next, prev). I would like to be active only arrow followed by another slide.

If I have a three slides. When the first slide shows the active button next active. When you view the second appears as active next and prev. When you view the third slide appears as only active prev.

**Example:**

- 3 slides:

  - first slide - only button **next** show
  - second slide - button **prev** and **next** show
  - third slide - only button **prev** show

**Live examples:**

[Live demo on my website](http://tatry.jinda.cz/)
[Testing example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zwsqdyn/)

jQuery:

```
$('.slideshow > ul')
  .before('<div class="wrapper"><div class="content"><div class="slide-nav">') 
  .cycle({ 
       fx:     'scrollLeft', 
       speed:  '600', 
       timeout: 4000, 
       pager:  '.slide-nav',
       next:   '#next', 
       prev:   '#prev'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="slide-ntx-prv">
                    <a id="prev" href=""><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></a>
                    <a id="next" href=""><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.content -->
        </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
        <ul>
            <li class="slide1">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div>cena/noc od <span class="green-bold">67 EUR</span></div>
                        <h2>Vysoké tatry<span>876 apartmánů</span></h2>
                    </div><!-- /.content -->
                </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
            </li>
            <li class="slide2">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div>cena/noc od <span class="green-bold">68 EUR</span></div>
                        <h2>Střední tatry<span>50 apartmánů</span></h2>
                    </div><!-- /.content -->
                </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
            </li>
            <li class="slide3">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div>cena/noc od <span class="green-bold">69 EUR</span></div>
                        <h2>Nízké tatry<span>236 apartmánů</span></h2>
                    </div><!-- /.content -->
                </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.slideshow -->
</div><!-- /#slideshow -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have access to the slides array and you know which is the current slide you can show/hide parts of the slide navigation.

Here is one working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zwsqdyn/1/) based on yours.

jQuery:

```
$('.slideshow > ul')
   .before('<div class="wrapper"><div class="content"><div class="slide-nav">') 
   .cycle({ 
        fx:     'scrollLeft', 
        speed:  '600', 
        timeout: 4000, 
        pager:  '.slide-nav',
        next:   '#next', 
        prev:   '#prev',

        nowrap: true,
        onPrevNextEvent: function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {
            if(zeroBasedSlideIndex == 0) {
                $('#prev').hide();
            } else {
                $('#prev').show();
            }

            if(zeroBasedSlideIndex == ($('#slideshow ul li').length - 1) ) {
                $('#next').hide();
            } else {
                $('#next').show();
            } 
        }
    });
```

Nowrap prevents the slides from looping.
onPrevNextEvent is the main part.